# Jinja2 template not found

Tags: python, html, jinja2, fastapi

I’m using `jinja2` templates with `Fastapi` and python to develop a web server. So when web browser do a get request, I will want to return a HTML page named `index.html`. However I’m seeing this error that says raise

```
TemplateNotFound(template) 
Jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
```

have a look at code below:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates  
  
app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
    
    
@app.get('/')
    def root(request: Request):
       return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

@app.get(‘/home’)
     def home(request:Request, firstname: Optional[Str] = None, lastname: Optional[Str] = None): 
     # process first name last name here 
      processName(firstname,lastname )
    
       return  templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

def processName(firstname, lastname):
      return “hi “ + firstname + “ “ + lastname
```

The HTML page displayed internal server error. It’s URL is showing

```
http://localhost:8000/home?firstname=May&lastname=June
```

Comment: Well, do you actually have a Jinja2 template in the file templates/index.html?

Comment: Yup I have. There is no issue when browser is launch and local host:8000 is keyed in the index.html is displayed. Issue surface only when browser did a query request.

Comment: please help with this for me if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661017/jinja2-template-not-found-unsolved

Answer (score 0):

I think you need only 3 spaces, and everything will work.

There are 3 sharps in the code below, replace them with spaces, and you should enjoy. :D

```
@app.get(‘/home’)
 def home(request:Request, firstname: Optional[Str] = None, lastname: Optional[Str] = None): 
 # process first name last name here
 
 ###return  templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

Comment: I have added some code for completeness sake. If the function processName() function is commented off, the return of HTML web page is fine. Why is that so?

Comment: You have to declare "processName" function before "home" function

Comment: please help with this for me if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661017/jinja2-template-not-found-unsolved

Answer (score 0):

For fastapi & jinja2 templates, you should use an absolute path,
for example:

main.py

```
from pathfile import Path

# some of codes here....

BASE_PATH = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
# lets say your template directory is under the root directory
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=f'{BASE_PATH}/templates')

@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def homepage(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})
```